I am trying to take values from multiple cells and inserting into one text string in google sheets
I am trying to take values from multiple cells and insert them as a string into another cell. My table has scores from a game between two players, I want to display the text string in a manner that shows the winning player and score.




A
B
C
D




1
Players
Points
Win %
Result


2
John
5
60.00%
John 5-4 (60%)


3
Eric
4
40.00%




string to insert into separate cell (D1 as the desired string format, including spaces, -, ()% characters)

Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange.

There are many ways to do that. Provided that there are just two players, one easy way is to use ifs(), like this:
=ifs( 
  B2 > B3, join(" ", A2, B2 & "-" & B3, "(" & to_text(C2) & ")"), 
  B2 < B3, join(" ", A3, B3 & "-" & B2, "(" & to_text(C3) & ")"), 
  true, "(tie)" 
)

See ifs().

Did you mean B3 & "-" & B2?

@BorisBaublys thanks.
